# Azure consumption API

Tags: azure, azure-management-api

I am trying to get the Azure Usage details by subscription,resource group. I am following the API steps as listed out here 
[Microsoft documentation for Usage API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/usagedetails/list#code-try-0)

I am getting a 200 response code when send a GET request like this

GET https://management.azure.com/%2Fsubscriptions%2F0000-00000-0000/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2019-01-01
Authorization: Bearer eyxxxx

But when I add the resource group to the scope I am getting 404(Resource not found error). I am absolutely sure that I have this resource group in my subscription.

GET https://management.azure.com/%2Fsubscriptions%2F00000-0000-0000%2FresourceGroups%2FXXX-XXXX/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2019-01-01
Authorization: Bearer eyXXX

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>404 - File or directory not found.</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body{margin:0;font-size:.7em;font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;background:#EEEEEE;}
fieldset{padding:0 15px 10px 15px;} 
h1{font-size:2.4em;margin:0;color:#FFF;}
h2{font-size:1.7em;margin:0;color:#CC0000;} 
h3{font-size:1.2em;margin:10px 0 0 0;color:#000000;} 
#header{width:96%;margin:0 0 0 0;padding:6px 2% 6px 2%;font-family:"trebuchet MS", Verdana, sans-serif;color:#FFF;
background-color:#555555;}
#content{margin:0 0 0 2%;position:relative;}
.content-container{background:#FFF;width:96%;margin-top:8px;padding:10px;position:relative;}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header"><h1>Server Error</h1></div>
<div id="content">
 <div class="content-container"><fieldset>
  <h2>404 - File or directory not found.</h2>
  <h3>The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.</h3>
 </fieldset></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think your URL should not contain "%2f", this corresponds to the encoded version of the character "/". The url should be :  https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000-0000-0000/resourceGroups/XXX-XXXX/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?api-version=2019-01-01

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's an issue with the documentation. I tried the same for a resource group scope and I also got the same 404 error.

One thing you could do is define `$filter` and specify `properties.resourceGroup eq 'Your Resource Group Name'`. I tried this and it worked for me.

[image]